# How i can get count of user from DB and show on a button in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to get the count of users from my database and want to show that count in a button. How can I do that in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For count of user, you could try

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }        

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["UserCount"] = _context.Users.Count();
        ViewData["Message"] = "Hello Word";

        return View();
    }      
}
```

For showing count on button, you could try

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "About";

}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>
<h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>

<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
<button>@ViewData["UserCount"]</button>
```